# Why Scifi not allowing me to post a question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

My [last question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254283/why-is-luna-lovegood-reading-this-book-upside-down) hit HNQ, but now Scifi not allowing me to post a question:

[image]

Comment: Because two of your last three questions are underwater. I'd suggest editing (or deleting) the one that's most heavily downvoted.

Comment: @Valorum As far as I'm aware deleting posts actually goes against you for the rate limiting and in any case the user won't be able to delete the questions because they both have upvoted answers.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Does disavowing them count against you?

Comment: @Valorum Disassociating the posts? No idea but it’s not really something that would happen just to avoid a question block.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I was thinking more because they're so heavily downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rate limit here is put in place by the system based on a number of factors, mostly though how well ***all*** your recent questions have been received, not just your latest one.

> ### How is the length of  time that I'm limited actually calculated?
>
> It's based on your average question score, how long you tend to wait between asking questions, how well you participate in other ways on the site, and how often you tend to revisit and improve your posts, even the positively scored ones. We don't provide the actual formula and details, only because we want folks to focus on what the system is trying to tell them, rather than trying to find ways around it.
>
> Rate limits vary from 1 to 7 days.
>
> <sub>[Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542/4631427)</sub>

The linked meta post above from SO meta has some good details about this case for you to look over, as does the [relevant help page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited). I suggest you read over some of the more general suggestions there and then see if you can improve your questions going forward. This might just be a false positive as your last question was well received but it's worth taking a step back and seeing if there is anything you need to do moving forward.